# How do I get a custom component that extends RelativeLayout programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Being new to Android the following issue drives me crazy, and not being able to Google an answer indicates that the solution is really simple...

I try to add a custom component (`ArticleView` extends `RelativeLayout`) to a `ViewGroup` (`LinearLayout`) from code but I cannot get access to the `ArticleView` object, trying to cast to it just throws an

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.eo.read/com.example.eo.read.ArticleInfoActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to com.example.eo.read.view.ArticleView
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to com.example.eo.read.view.ArticleView
        at com.example.eo.read.ArticleInfoActivity.onCreate(ArticleInfoActivity.java:44)
```

In my `Activity` class I do:

```
package com.example.eo.read;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.example.eo.read.content.Article;
import com.example.eo.read.content.ArticleDB;
import com.example.eo.read.view.ArticleView;
...

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_article_info);

    _article = ArticleDB.getInstance().getArticle("test");

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //get the linear layout into which the ArticleView is going
    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.recommendation_container);

    //get the custom component
    RelativeLayout ra = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);

    //this causes the classcast exception, although this RelativeLayout really should be an ArticleView
    ((ArticleView)ra).setArticle(_article);

    //adding the ArticleView to the container works fine, and the customizations 
    //I have made in ArticleView are visible, so indeed it seems ra is an ArticleView ??
    container.addView(ra);

}
```

The (simplified) `article_view.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="260dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/stroked_grey_plate">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="Sample text"
    android:textColor="#111111"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout for the activity contains the id/recommedation_container into which the `ArticleView` is being inserted. Below is also the same view inserted declaratively, just for clarity:

```
<LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/recommendation_container"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
    <com.example.eo.read.view.ArticleView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         custom:titleText="my title text"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

The `ArticleView` class is essentially:

```
package com.example.eo.read.view;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet; 
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.eo.read.R;
import com.example.eo.read.content.Article;

public class ArticleView extends RelativeLayout {
private TextView _titleView;
private Article _article;

public ArticleView(Context context) {
    this(context,null);
}

public ArticleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.ArticleView, 0, 0);

//in the case where the ArticleView is declared in XML the title is retreived from a custom attribute, this works fine.    
String titleText = a.getString(R.styleable.ArticleView_titleText);

    a.recycle();

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, this, true);

    ViewGroup rl = (ViewGroup)getChildAt(0); //get the RelativeLayout

    _titleView = (TextView) rl.getChildAt(0);
    _titleView.setText(titleText);

} 

//in the case where the ArticleView is initiated from code the title should be set by calling this method, 
//which I never can reach since I cannot get to this ArticleView object from my activity :-(
//I realize this class is maybe not fully functional yet but first step is to actually be able to initiate it...
public void setArticle(Article a) {
    _article = a;
    _titleView.setText(_article.getTitle());
}
}
```

So, my question is pretty much.. why can't I do:

```
ArticleView ra = (ArticleView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
```

and what should I instead do to get to my `ArticleView`?

Comment: What happens when you do `ArticleView ra = (ArticleView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.recommended_article_view, container, false);`? It should be okay to do it like this...

Comment: can you please show me the imports?

Comment: I'm on the bus now so I can't show the imports but note that the custom component is added just fine to the parent layout and rendered as specified in its layout. Wouldnt this indicate that the imports are ok? Regarding the package names I removed them (maybe bad idea) in order to make the code easier to read. But they are correct I believe (since everything but the gast works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add the custom view programmatically and not have it defined in the XML?

If that is the case, what happens if you simply do:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_article_info);

    _article = ArticleDB.getInstance().getArticle("test");

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //get the linear layout into which the ArticleView is going
    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.recommendation_container);

    //get the custom component
    ArticleView av = new ArticleView(this);


    av.setArticle(_article);


    container.addView(av);

}
```

In case you haven't stumbled upon it yet, it seems this blog has some nice tips regarding custom views: http://trickyandroid.com/protip-inflating-layout-for-your-custom-view/

If you would like to have your Custom view inflated together with your layout, then you can do:

```
<LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/recommendation_container"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
    <com.example.eo.read.view.ArticleView
      android:id="@+id/article" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         custom:titleText="my title text"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

Just taking the XML from your question as an example, not sure how well it fits your situation.

But now, inflating the above XML to a view called, say, `root` and then doing `root.findViewById(R.id.article)` should return a view which can be cast to ArticleView.

Thinking about it, if you have an XML file like this:

```
    <com.example.eo.read.view.ArticleView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         custom:titleText="my title text"
     />
```

You actually should be able to inflate it, as you are trying, and cast to ArticleView, since com.example.eo.read.view.ArticleView is now the root of the layout.

Comment: This works fine! Thanks. Is there any added benefit by doing it the way I originally tried to do it (initiating the object via the layoutinflater) instead of doing it as you suggest? If not I can just do it this way instead.

Comment: Well, depends on the use case I guess. If you wish to create some advanced custom view with a lot of custom attributes, it could be better to just define it all in XML instead of having to create and insert the view programatically.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `ArticleView` in your XML file with `[packagename].ArticleView`

For example, if your `ArticleView` class is contained in `com.john.article`, then your `ArticleView` should be replaced by `com.john.article.ArticleView`.

Comment: yes, I am using package names, I just removed it in the example to make it more readable, but I have added it now. However, it is not this causing the failure.